# SQL - How To List True Case Statements In 1 Field

Tags: mysql, sql

My current SQL statement groups certain colors and certain fruits as 2 new columns (Colors, Fruit) and adds + 1 whenever either respective column is greater than 0.

I want whenever Colors, or Fruits, is > 0, to have the name listed in the column "NewColumn".

Here is an example, with the last column being the expected output.

[image]

You can see Tom Brady does not have "Fruit" in the NewColumn, as the value is 0 for "Fruit".

Here Is My Current Code

```sql
SELECT
  *,
  (  (CASE WHEN apple > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
   + (CASE WHEN WHEN grapes > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) as fruit,
  (  (CASE WHEN red > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
   + (CASE WHEN blue > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) as colors
from table
```

Comment: Show us what you've written so far. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @J_H query has been added

Comment: Your current code has a syntax error (`WHEN WHEN` )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just add up color and fruit counts to get their totals and see whether you get a count greater than zero. Use `CASE` expressions for the texts 'Colors' and 'Fruits'. Use `CONCAT_WS` for the concatenation.

```
select
  blue, red, apple, grapes,
  concat_ws(',', 
    case when blue + red > 0 then 'Colors' end,
    case when apple + grapes > 0 then 'Fruits' end
  ) as new_column
from mytable;
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is work for you.

```
Select *, 
    case When Fruit>0 and Colors > 0 then 'Colors;Fruit' 
         when Fruit > 0 and Colors = 0 then 'Fruit' 
         when Fruit = 0 and Colors > 0 then 'Colors' end as NewColumn 
From Example
```

Comment: `Fruit` and `Colors` are output expression aliases, not columns.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subquery to get the value of your `NewColumn`. Additional `select case` for this newly added column.

```
select t.*, case when t.Colors > 0 and t.Fruit > 0 then 'Colors;Fruit'
    when t.Colors > 0 and t.Fruit = 0 then 'Colors'
    when t.Colors = 0 and t.Fruit > 0 then 'Fruit'
    else '' end as NewColumn
from (
    select case when Red+Blue > 0 then Red+Blue else 0 end as Colors
        , case when Apple+Grapes > 0 then Apple+Grapes else 0 end as Fruit
        , Blue, Red, Apple, Grapes
    from table) as t
```

Comment: When is missing first line after case